# Meteor event when user sign in

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I added to meteor "accounts-ui accounts-password" package and i want to execute this function when user signed in.

```
({ function() { alert("Hello") } })
```

But i didn't find any function in google only hacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Accounts.onLogin`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin) like this,

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Accounts.onLogin(function () {
        var user = Meteor.user();
        alert(user.profile.firstName + ' is logged in.');
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I didn't use it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you [this link](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_ui_config) for more informations, try with this code and be sure that you have added the **service-configuration** package.

```
  Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    facebook: ['user_likes'],
    github: ['user', 'repo']
  },
  requestOfflineToken: {
    google: true
  },
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_OPTIONAL_EMAIL'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the template when you use:

**your-login.html**

```
<template name="yourLogin">
    {{> LoginButtons}}
</template>
```

You can use any of the template functions callbacks

**your-login.js**

```
Template.yourLogin.rendered = function () {
   Tracker.autorun (function () {
     if (Meteor.user ())
       alert("Hello");
   });
};
```

You can actually use the same code within any Tracker.autorun because Meteor.user () works in any reactive  context

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if ( Meteor.userId() ){
     alert(Meteor.userId() + "hello")  
 }
```